# Getting an input from command-line and passing it to a method

Tags: java, command-line

I'm getting a string array from command line and displaying it to user as integer array. What could be the mistake here?

```
import java.lang.String;

public class arrayConvert {

    String strArray[];

    public int[] StrArrtoIntArr(String strArray[])
    {
        int intArray[] = new int[strArray.length];

        for(int count=0;count<strArray.length;count++)
        {
            intArray[count] = Integer.parseInt(strArray[count]);
        }

        return intArray;
    }

    public void displayArray(int intArray [])
    {
        for(int j=0;j<intArray.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(intArray[j]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        arrayConvert array_convert = new arrayConvert();
        array_convert.StrArrtoIntArr(args);
        array_convert.displayArray(intArray);
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the 'mistake' you're seeing? Is the wrong thing being printed? Is there an exception?

Comment: You need to tell us what the behaviour is, and we'll suggest how to fix it. Please tell us if this is homework.

Comment: The error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: arrayConvert

Comment: Did you have a look at your classpath? Is it set correctly?

Comment: @Scharrels Yep! Checked the classpath just now. Also tried executing in an IDE. Still I get the same error.

Comment: It executes fine in the Eclipse build i've got here (3.4.2)

Comment: I'm using Netbeans IDE 6.5.1 & I'm getting that error still! Well well..

Comment: It must be something with your build environment. Your program is correct (except the error in the main class I pointed out). Is your program in a certain directory (package)? In that case, you need to put a package declaration on top of your file. Search for an error in that direction.

Comment: Yep. I created a package and removed the unused global variable and I got it. Thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to save the intermediate result in you main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    arrayConvert array_convert = new arrayConvert();
    int[] intArray = array_convert.StrArrtoIntArr(args);
    array_convert.displayArray(intArray);
}
```

There are some more things in your code, you might want to look at:

- `import java.lang.String;` You don't need to include this. java.lang is automatically imported.
- `String strArray[];` This variable is never used. The variable `strArray[]` in `StrArrtoIntArr` is a different variable in a different (local) scope. Keeping the global variable might be confusing.

Comment: Oh ya! I saved the intermediate results and yet I get the error as I typed above.

Comment: You're right. I guess that's not the entire program. That was just step one and I had that global variable in mind for a different purpose. Anyways great observation Scharrels :)

Answer (score 0):

Hand-written code for parsing command-line arguments is unnecessary and tedious, especially when you need to do extensive parsing. Use a 3rd-party library instead, like [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/cli/).

Comment: Is that relevant in this particular case ?

Comment: @Brian: It's relevant if he's wasting time parsing command-line arguments, when he could be spending that time solving real problems.

Answer (score 0):

Damn beat me to the punch!

you forgot to store you array of ints as:

```
int[] intArray = array_convert.StrArrtoIntArr(args);
```

Comment: Thank you Brendan. Got the result. That was so silly of me of not saving the intermediate result. Happens with me atleast :)

Comment: Happens to the best of us. Just read through your code when your stuck, and you should figure it out. Believe me, I've done stupider things...